# What the best clockify API endpoint to get time entries of (grouped by) saved reports?

Tags: clockify

Asking here, after asking to Clockify support.

Trying to extend some of clockify capabilities to create extra reporting for our clients, 
I’ve been playing with your API and specifically: the enpoint /reports/{reportsId}

• **My goal**:

Get all the time entries of a specific "saved report” (usually saved by our Project Managers)

• **What I EXPECT from "/reports/{reportsId}”**:

To get all the info and entities (users, time entries, projects, etc.) only regarding that particular reportId

• **What I GET from "/reports/{reportsId}”**:

Lots of info regarding the whole workspace, and I only see summaryReport
as more “specific to the saved report itself”...

• **Questions**:

1. Is this the correct behavior?
2. How do you filter down time entries of specific reports in URLs like https://clockify.me/bookmarks/BOOKMARK_HASH_HERE ?

   - Do you only call "/reports/{reportsId}” and filter down on client-side? (it seems to me that way, exploring the Network tab)
   - If that’s the way, what’s the point of calling the report endpoint? Only for the summaryReport object?
     3- Is "/reports/{reportsId}” the best endpoint I can use to reach my goal? …or which way would you recommend me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`summaryReport.timeEntries` will contain all the individual time entries from that particular report. Each entry has a user, project, client, time etc. Grouping by project is done on the client.

I'm not sure I fully understand your specific problem though. Are you suggesting the entries you get from the report endpoint do not belong to the given report?

Comment: ouch. How I could not see that?!? :D Thanks!

but yeah...I'm suggesting that many of the info I'm getting from many endpoints...are general info, not strictly regarging the specific endpoint I call. That's what definitely helped me driving off road.